# Use a variable reference "inside" another variable

Tags: shell-script, ksh, variable-substitution

I'm sure it is relatively simple, I just don't know how to do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
set `iostat`
myvar=6
```

I want to something like `echo ${$myvar}` which i want interpreted as `${$myvar}` -> `${6}` -> `value`

Comment: The technical term is _variable indirection_.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do this with `eval`, built-in to many fine shells, including ksh:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
set $(iostat)
myvar=6
eval "echo \${$myvar}"
```

The trick is to double-quote the string you feed to `eval` so that $myvar gets substituted with "6", and to backslash the outer dollar-sign, so that `eval` gets a string "$6".

I got "%user" for the output, but I tried it on a multi-processor RHEL machine.

Comment: You are officially the Supreme Exalted Grand Master of the week b/c that even works on the unfathomably awful ksh (really pdksh) in OpenBSD 5.4. If you want to set var **vv** to the value of the var whose name is in the var **vn**, just do `vv=$( eval "echo \$$vn" )`.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 38):

### Indirect variable reference

Modern advanced shells have a method to reference the value of a variable whose name is stored in another variable. Unfortunately the method differs between ksh, bash and zsh.

In mksh ≥R39b, you can make `myvar` a nameref:

```
typeset -n myvar=6
echo "$myvar"
```

This doesn't work in ATT ksh93 because it doesn't support namerefs to positional parameters. In the case where you have a variable containing a variable name, you can use this method.

```
foo=bar
typeset -n myvar=foo
echo "$myvar"  # prints bar
```

In bash ≥2.0, you can write

```
echo "${!myvar}"
```

In zsh, you can write

```
echo ${(P)myvar}
```

In older shells, including ksh88 and pdksh, your only recourse when you have a variable containing another variable name and want to use the value of this variable `eval`, [as explained by Bruce Ediger](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41409). This solution works in any Bourne/POSIX shell.

```
eval "value=\${$myvar}"
echo "$value"
```

### Using an array

This is the best method here: it's simpler and more portable.

For your use case, in any shell with arrays (all ksh variants, bash ≥2.0, zsh), you can assign to an array variable and take the element you wish. Beware that ksh and bash arrays start numbering at 0, but zsh starts at 1 unless you issue `setopt ksh_arrays` or `emulate ksh`.

```
set -A iostat -- $(iostat)
echo "${iostat[5]}"
```

If you want to copy the positional parameters to an array variable `a`:

```
set -A a -- "$@"
```

In ksh93, mksh ≥R39b, bash ≥2.0 and zsh, you can use the array assignment syntax:

```
iostat=($(iostat))
echo "${iostat[5]}"
```

Comment: Wow, your 'Bourne/POSIX' solution also works in OpenBSD 5.4's ksh/pdksh. To apply it to the example in my comment to Bruce Ediger's answer above, just do `eval "vv=\${$vn}"`.  Merci beaucoup, kind sir.

Comment: `echo ${(P)myvar}` is `p` a var, like `p=1`?

Comment: @Timo I guess you're asking about `(P)`? It's a [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

Comment: I have code: `s_cust_plugin='s|custom/plugins/'; echo "b=$0\na=${((P)s_cust_plugin$1/|)b}\necho $a[2] loaded"`. Result:`add_zsh_plugin:2: error in flags` -- I want to echo the name of script that I invoke with `exec zsh` after adding this code to the script.

Comment: @Timo What you wrote is syntactically incorrect and I can't figure out what you intended to do. This is too complicated for a comment. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by Gilles (who provided the `bash` part of the answer), also not invalidating Bruce Ediger’s (on how to do it portably with `eval`), here’s how to do it with `nameref` in recent `mksh` (and AT&T ksh93, except – as @Gilles commented – namerefs cannot refer to positional parameters in AT&T ksh, only to named parameters):

```
#!/bin/mksh
set -- $(iostat)
nameref myvar=6
echo $myvar
```

Added the `--` after `set` for improved resistence, too.

Comment: As of ksh 93u, namerefs can't reference positional parameters (`typeset: 6: invalid variable name`).

Answer (score 0):

### Another use of arrays

Haven't used either ksh or any variant for some time, so I'm not sure if ksh(or bash) has a similar capability.  My primary shell is zsh.  I use arrays when handling output from commands like *iostat* because they produce multiple lines, and not all lines are the same format/length.

```
#! /bin/zsh
IOStatOutput=("${(@f)$(iostat)}") # Produces one element per line
```

The above also bypasses the use of positional parameters. Now, if you want to generate, say, an array of devices:

```
for Element in {7..${#IOStatOutput}} # Devices listed in elements 7 thru the last
do
    DevList+=( ${${=IOStatOutput[Element]}[1]} )
done
```

I find smaller chunks much easier to handle. You may or may not need to use indirect variable reference, depending on your code.  Knowing how it works is still a good thing to know.  I use it myself.