# Parsing a file to determine what values to use

Tags: bash, variable

I have a script and a "config" file that pull variables from.  I created the configuration file called config.cfg and used it in my script as such:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ -f ./config.cfg ]
   then 
       source ./config.cfg
   else
       exit
```

The config files contains a number of different things like

```
title="Foo Bar - The Untold Story"
desc="This is a verbose description of Foo Bar's Untold Story"
author="S. Nafu"
date="01/01/1932"
image_url="./path_to_image/foo.bar.jpg"
image_link="http://www.foo.bar/foo_bar"
```

So far, eveything works because I can issue (in the script) the command:

```
echo $title
```

and get

```
Foo Bar - The Untold Story
```

**What I am Trying to Accomplish**

I want to create an XML file based on these fields and attributes.  Ideally,  want to parse the file and determine if the variable was declared, not if it has a value or not.  So...here is the code I came up with:

```
function writeln 
{
   local attrib=$1
   local value=$2
   local fmt="%s%s%s\n" 
   printf $fmt "<$attrib>$value</$attrib>"
}

function writeChannel
{
    local fmt="%s\n"
    printf $fmt "<channel>"
    while read line
    do
        local xml_attrib=`echo $line | cut -d "=" -f1`
        local xml_value=`echo $line | tr -d '"' | cut -d "=" -f2`
        writeln $xml_attrib $xml_value

    done < config.cfg

}
```

When I execute the code, I get what is expected:

```
<title>Foo Bar - the Untold Story</title>
<desc>This is a verbose description of Foo Bar's Untold Story</desc>
....
```

Now, what I would like to do is **use** the variable "title" based on what I parsed (assume I don't know that the variables name is "title")

Basically, I want to do take the *xml_attrib* variable, concatenate a "$" to it and then get the contents.  So, using the first line of my *config.cfg* file,

```
xml_attrib = "title"
```

How would I address that string as a var and say

```
echo $title
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [variable indirection](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41406/use-a-variable-reference-inside-another-variable), eg `"echo \$$myvar"`

Comment: Side note: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can do indirection on a variable with the syntax
`${!var}`.  E.g.

```
 a=x; b=a; echo "${!b}"  # gives you x
```

Other bash-isms you might like can replace eg:

```
xml_attrib=`echo $line | cut -d "=" -f1`
xml_value=`echo $line | tr -d '"' | cut -d "=" -f2`
```

by

```
xml_attrib=${line%%=*}
line=${line#*=}
xml_value=${line//\"/}
```

See bash(1), Parameter Expansion.

Comment: Note that while `${var%%}` and `${var#*=}` are standard, ${line//\"/} is a kshism (and zsh and bash).