# makefile value of variable is a the name of another variable

Tags: make, variable-substitution

In a makefile, the value of variable is a the name of another variable. How do I get it inside target?

For example:

```make
my_variable := Hello

target:
    @var_name="my_variable" ; \
    result=$($(var_name)) ; \
    echo $$result
```

The `result` should be `Hello`.

Or another example:

```make
VALUES123 := 1 2 3
CLIENTS_1_IP := 10.100
CLIENTS_2_IP := 10.100
CLIENTS_3_IP := 10.100

cll: 
    @for value in ${VALUES123}; do \
        var_name="CLIENTS_$${value}_IP"; \
        echo $$var_name; \
        $(eval CLIENT := $(value $$(var_name))) \
        echo $$CLIENT; \
    done
```

I need something instead of

```
$(eval CLIENT := $(value $$(var_name)))
```

which will work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a variable reference "inside" another variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41406/use-a-variable-reference-inside-another-variable)